# Почему в слове «ранний» пишутся две буквы Н?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, прилагательные, нн

Допустим, слово происходит от существительного **рань**, но почему у наречия, образованного от него, одна Н (**рано**)? Это противоречит правилу.
И если это исключение, то по какой причине оно стало исключением?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...по какой причине оно стало исключением?

Из [***Бешенкова Е.В., Иванова О.Е., Чельцова Л.К. "Объяснительный русский орфографический словарь-справочник". М., 2015***]:

> **рано** (др.-рус., ст.-слав. рано)
>
> Слово означало "утро", от него образовано прилагательное *ранний*.
>   Обычно наречия на *-о* образуются от прилагательных, но это слово
>   принадлежит к числу так называемых первообразных.

Answer (score 0):

**Ранний**. Два Н. 
Тут не надо ни правил, ни исключений: **ран** - корень, **н+ий** - суффикс плюс окончание.

А у "**рано**" нет этого суффикса. 
Есть корень "ран" и окончание о (некоторые, правда, считают О особым суффиксом, но это уже из другой темы).

Comment: *Есть правило: в наречии пишется столько букв «н», сколько пишется в производящем прилагательном* - не в "наречии", а в его **суффиксах**. https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/n-nn-v-suffiksah-prilagatelnyh-prichastiy-i-narechiyah в "рано" вообще нет суффикса. И еще очень большой вопрос, что чего породило. "Ранний", боюсь не производит наречия вро\овсе. Как "синий".